# How to set up a simulation on QUCS for a RF differential source?

Tags: rf, qucs

I need to set up some simulations on QUCS for the RF circuit below:

[image]

Pin1 is the IC's positive port and Pin2 is the IC's negative port.

My initial goal is to investigate the circuit behavior at different frequencies and different lumped components values. After that, I want to calculate the impedance matching and best PCB transmission line.

I saw many QUCS examples, but all of those use a single power source.

How can I setup a differential signal source on QUCS? Pointing to an example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first two letters of qusc stand for "quite universal" so, if it's as good as its name then use two sources that generate antiphase signals. Or use one source and a voltage controlled voltage source (inverting configuration) to generate the other.

Comment: This should work, but if you plan on using the s parameter excitation source you will have to combine the responses of both ports with some equation. You also need to terminate the reflected common mode signals. Another approach which I used in ADS is to use an ideal 4 port balun. QUCS doesn't have such a device built in AFAIK but you can probably model one with a transformer or an equation based model.